# Duplicated project executable give "Data Formatters temporarily unavailable" error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I made a duplicate of my (working) executable without changing anything. Unfortunately, I am receiving the following error immediately and the emulator window doesn't appear:

> Data formatters temporarily
>   unavailable, will re-try after a
>   'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen
>   at this time.)

Answer (score 0):

Check all links to libraries, if you use non-standard ones.